# How to parallelize model prediction from a pytorch model?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have a PyTorch instance segmentation model that predicts the masks of images one by one. Is there any way to parallelize this task so that it can be completed faster. I have tried to use multiprocessing `pool.apply_async()` to call the method that performs prediction passing the required arguments, but it throws me segmentation fault. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should be able to use [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack) to stack multiple images together into a batch and then feed that to your model. I can't say for certain without seeing your model, though. (ie. if your model was built to explicitly handle one image at a time, this won't work)

```
model = ... # Load your model

input1 = torch.randn(3, 32, 32)  # An RGB input image
input2 = torch.randn(3, 32, 32)  # An RGB input image 

model_input = torch.stack((input1, input2))
print(model_input.shape)         # (2, 3, 32, 32)

result = model(model_input)
print(result.shape)              # (2, 1, 32, 32) 2 output masks, one for each image
```

If you've trained the model yourself this will look familiar as it's essentially how we feed batches of images to the network during training.

You can stack more than two together, it will typically be limited by the amount of GPU memory you have available to you.